# Convert column into rows in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pivot-table

I have Pandas dataframe with two columns. One is unique identifier and second is the name of product attached to this unique identifier. I have duplicate values for identifier and product names. I want to convert one column of product names into several columns without duplicating identifier. Maybe I need to aggregate product names through identifier.

My dataframe looks like:

```
ID  Product_Name
100  Apple
100  Banana
200  Cherries
200  Apricots
200  Apple
300  Avocados
```

I **want to have** dataframe like this:

```
ID 
100  Apple Banana
200  Cherries Apricots Apple
300  Avocados
```

Each product along each identifier has to be in separate column

I tried `pd.melt`, `pd.pivot`, `pd.pivot_table` but only errors and this errors says `No numeric types to aggregate`

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for new columns names to `MultiIndex` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['ID',df.groupby('ID').cumcount()])['Product_Name'].unstack()
```

Or create `Series` of `list`s and new `DataFrame` by contructor:

```
s = df.groupby('ID')['Product_Name'].apply(list)
df = pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index)
```

---

```
print (df)
            0         1      2
ID                            
100     Apple    Banana    NaN
200  Cherries  Apricots  Apple
300  Avocados       NaN    NaN
```

But if want 2 column `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('ID')['Product_Name'].apply(' '.join).reset_index(name='new')
print (df1)
    ID                      new
0  100             Apple Banana
1  200  Cherries Apricots Apple
2  300                 Avocados
```

Answer (score 1):

use pivot funtion [pivoting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) it can do the required thing!!